# Is there a way to disable mouseover on highcharts entirely?

Tags: events, user-interface, highcharts, mouse, mouseevent

I'm building a website that uses highcharts. When I view the site on a mobile device, touching within the graph area pops up the tooltip, which prevents scrolling. I have tried all of the following, as suggested in other SO questions, without success:

```
$('#graph-container').click(function() { return false; });
$('#graph-container').children().click(function() { return false; });
chart.container.onclick = null;

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false // (stops tooltip but still blocks scrolling)
    }
}
```

For now I've added a second div that covers the graph on mobile devices, so the user touches the div instead of the graph, but that is more a workaround than a solution. I also tried removing all listeners from every element of the graph using things like $('svg').off() in Chrome's console, without any noticeable change in the graph's behaviour. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.enabled

Comment: I had not, though I tried it just now and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find simple [Gist](https://gist.github.com/slawekkolodziej/2983403) for that.

Also, in upcoming Highcharts 3.0 touch events should be upgraded and fixed similar issues. See roadmap: http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap

Comment: I thought this was working, but it turns out I still had my covering div over top of it. I'm using highstock, and there's a comment on the Gist page about it not working for highstock, but when it worked for me I thought it had to with the version the other person was using; nope. This really feels like the correct answer though; do you know of a fix to get it working in highstock?

Comment: For that Gist? I don't know, but today Highcharts 3.0 Beta was released - try it and share with suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not an updated Highstock, just Highcharts.

Comment: No, both are updated. Have you tried to open Highstock? See: http://github.highcharts.com/v3.0Beta/highstock.js

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts JS v2.3.5 (2012-12-19)

Little HACK:

edit Line: 9026: this.setDOMEvents();

into: // this.setDOMEvents();

or delete it.

I hope it helped!